# What is current steering and charge steering?

Tags: current, charge

'Charge Steering: A Low-Power Design Paradigm' by Razavi. I was reading the paper and came across these two terms.I tried googling but did not get a proper result, I have no clue what these are. Can someone suggest a material or maybe give a brief explanation about what current/charge steering means?

PS: Can you please tell me if any more details are required.

Comment: Where were you reading this?

Comment: It was a paper written by Razavi, Charge Steering: A Low-Power Design Paradigm @Frog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paper, current steering refers to the common method of steering a current source to/from resistive loads to develop a voltage signal. We have current steering DACs that switch currents to resistive loads and develop a voltage signal in communications circuits, for example. However, a circuit like a differential pair also steers current to loads, and can be used for amplification. Most of analog cmos design relies on this type of continuous architecture in signal processing stages. It is also used in pre-amplifiers for comparators.

His paper shows a novel approach to use charge steering to develop a multitude of new architectures based on transferring charges discretely, rather than the ubiquitous continuous current steering used in common design. In charge steering, one steers charge from a common source capacitance to capacitive loads in order to develop the signal voltages. Not only can it be used in common analog gain and signal processing circuits, but digital circuitry as well.

The charge steering works similarly to switched capacitor circuitry, whereby a charge is transferred to/from capacitors dynamically at discrete intervals. The charge transfer allows voltage signal processing, similar to current steering. However, because it is discrete rather than continuous, it can offer large advantages in current and power savings.

According to Razavi, it can be substituted in many common analog current steering based designs, and offers significant advantages in speed and power. I haven't seen this used much in modern designs, but it does appear to be a paradigm if it works as well as described.  He doesn't discuss common problems with charged based circuits, like unwanted charge injection, so certainly there will be challenges as well.

https://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Conferences/BRazaviCICC13.pdf

If you are more interested in finding a good common current steering application, I recommend to go look up current steering digital to analog converters. For discrete charge transferring, I'd look into common switched capacitor literature if you aren't already familiar with it (like multiplying DACs).

Comment: This is a good high-level review of the paper, but could you try to explain what "current steering" actually is, as well as what it means to "develop a voltage signal"?

Comment: @Johonn. I think of it as steering one or more current sources (e.g. DAC diff pairs) to one of a pair resistive loads (usually) The loads are resistors. The current 'steered to resistive loads develops a voltage signal across them. The cap steering does the same, but steers charge to capacitors instead of current to resistors, in order to get  voltage signal across the loads. See Fig. 2. http://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Journals/BRWinter18DAC.pdf